# Android studio Error:For input string: "<!"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build this project: [Calculator](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calculator).

I successfully import it in Adnroid studio, and I get the following error:
[Android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmjH4.jpg):

```
Gradle 'Simple-Calculator-master' project refresh failed
Error:For input string: "<!"
```

Highlighting the following line in my gradle.properties file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

I have no `<!` in my gradle.properties nor in my project. How should I solve the problem?

Comment: `clean-rebuild`. `distributionUrl=https\://`